# Extra whitespace that causes a newline by UITextView at end is ignored

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview, nstextcontainer

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        let textView = UITextView(frame: .zero)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(textView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
           textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
            textView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            textView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])

        // As we can see, LOT'S of whitespace at the end.
        textView.text = "Some Random Text That Has Whitespaces At The End                                                        "

        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

**By the amount of spaces, it should have created an empty newline**. However, as we can see this wasn't the case. If I add another character at the very end of the string, the newline will be shown (but with the character, which I do not want).

How can I show an empty newline if needed in an `UITextView`?

Comment: How about `"\n"`?

Comment: Note that you have the same behavior when writing a message on Message.app

Comment: @LinusGeffarth That always creates a newline. The UITextView should only append a newline if it is needed

Comment: @Larme yes, that is accomplished by removing the leading & trailing whitespaces. I must keep them.

Comment: Wait, can you please clear up what you're trying to do? What do you mean by *if needed*?

Comment: I'm wondering if using another "invisible" char at the end would do the trick.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I have a string with lots of whitespaces at the end. The textview just ignores it. I don't want that.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure if the text field ignores it. The space after "end" seems to be enough to fit the textview. Try adding more spaces to see if it works.

Comment: @Xcoder not enough??? The amount of whitespaces is equal to the existing text. But it does not matter how many whitespaces there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

> ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎

There is some **invisible** characters inside the quote that iOS is not count them as `whiteSpace`

Comment: I've used this and it worked for me in 90% of the cases, I have a few where the last line is nonetheless cut off. Do you have any other solution? In my case I'm using a `UILabel`

Comment: @Niklas you found a solution?

Comment: Nope. Did you @J.Doe?

Comment: @Niklas I have an extremely hacky solution by using NSMutableAttributedString. Long story short: append something like '     |' behind your text, wrap in inside an NSMutableAttributedString and change the color of the last character (which is |) to UIColor.clear. Than it always works in every scenario

Answer (score 0):

to add extra lines use "\n" for example:

```
textView.text = "Some Random Text That Has Whitespaces At The End \n\n"
```

Result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkCmc.jpg

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: @J.Doe 
Post Question: how can I show an empty newline if needed in an UITextView?
Answer: to add extra lines use "\n"
Did I get it wrong?

Comment: No. You point out exactly the problem with your answer: you always show a newline. You literally quoted the words 'if needed'.