# Howto change from proportional to tabulated digits in menu items?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I want to change from proportional to tabulated digits in menu items? It's possible?

[Menu without tabulated digits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMQ2v.png)

Comment: Your question asked for how to add tabs to format your menu items. Although the accepted answer shows how to get around needing tabs it doesn’t answer your question as it was asked. If the answer satisfies your need please consider editing the question so that the answer and the question match.

Comment: I read it as asking about monospaced digits, fwiw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the monospaced font like this:

```
label.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
```

Obviously you can specify whatever font size and weight you want (or get them from the current font descriptor).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`attributedTitle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenuitem/1514860-attributedtitle) property of a [`NSMenuItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenuitem) and provide whatever custom alignment or formatting you want through an [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring)

Good examples of how to do string alignment in an attributed string can be seen here:

[Attributed Text Center Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045750/attributed-text-center-alignment)

Here is an answer that shows how to add tab stops to an attributed string:

[How do I add tab stops to an NSAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34211974/887210)

You can even create an attributed string from RTF or HTML:

[Creating an NSAttributedString from HTML (or RTF)](https://coderwall.com/p/boizxa/creating-an-nsattributedstring-from-html-or-rtf-in-ios-7)